# Build a new string from every nth character of a string

Tags: php, regex, string, character, text-extraction

I have a long string from which I need to get every 12th character. I currently do it with a `for()` loop, but I'm wondering if there is a better/more efficient way.

```
$verylongstring = 'thisisalongstringwithawholelotofcharctersitgoesonforawhile...loremipsum'; 
$newstring = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($verylongstring); $i++) 
{ 
    if ($i % 12 == 0) {
        $newstring .= $verylongstring[$i];
    }
} 
echo $newstring;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little `preg_replace()` should work for you -

```
$verylongstring='thisisalongstringwithawholelotofcharctersitgoesonforawhileloremipsum'; 
$newString = preg_replace('/(.).{11,11}/', '$1', $verylongstring);
echo $newString;
```

Here is an example - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gf4i-6221

Comment: I actually modified the regex a bit  using some of Mike Samuels snippet. I was getting "eloremipsum" at the end. '/(.).{11,11}|.{1,11}/'. thank you both.

Comment: This unexplained answer does not implement the require logic nor does it deliver the desired output. https://3v4l.org/cP4Yl It returns `ttocnremipsum` instead of `shroo`. This script isolates: the 1st, 13th, 25th, 37th, and 49th characters then all remaining characters in the string. This answer is certainly misleading readers. The `{11,11}` quantifier is a bad smell too.

Comment: Reaching back a bit @mickmackusa ?

Answer (score 0):

Match the first eleven characters then capture the twelfth character; if this subpattern is satisfied, replace all twelve chatacters with the twelfth character.  Otherwise, match the remainder of the string (eleven characters or less) and replace those characters with an empty string (the unpopulated first capture group).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9TDNQ))

```
echo preg_replace('/.{11}(.)|.*/', '$1', $verylongstring);
// shroo
```

Or without alternation, greedily match upto eleven characters (not giving back), then capture the twelfth character if it exists. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q1udI)

```
echo preg_replace('/.{1,11}(.?)/', '$1', $verylongstring);
```